# Delete p execution in destructor

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

I do have doubt regarding use of `delete p`. In most of the scenarios we call delete inside the destructor if we would have called something `int *p = new int (10);` but as per below code snippet (original code of delete p) it already invoke the destructor then call the operator delete then why we should call delete p inside the destructor.

Original code:

```
delete a;
if (a != NULL) {
  a->~A();
  operator delete(a);
}
```

code snippet where we call the delete a inside destructor

```
class B
{
  int *a;
  public:
  B()
  {
    a=new int(90);
  }
  ~B()
  {
    cout<<"B's destructor";
    delete a;
  }
  void dial()
  {
    cout<<"dial the tone";
  }
}
```

Comment: *"In most of the scenarios we call delete inside the destructor"*: I would say in most scenarios we do not call `delete` at all, nor `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that! This is a double destroy and a double free

```
delete a;             // calls destructor and then frees the memory
if (a != NULL) {
  a->~A();            // calls destructor again
  operator delete(a); // frees memory again
}
```

This one is ok, because you allocated the memory in the constructor

```
~B()
{
    cout<<"B's destructor";
    delete a;
}
```

With [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), you can use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead

```
class B
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> a;
public:
    B() : a(new int(90));
    {
    }
    ~B()
    {
        cout<<"B's destructor";
        // std::unique_ptr will take care of memory
        // no delete a neccessary
    }
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `operator delete` and `delete expression` are not same. Defaulted `operator delete` only freed memory, but expression calls destructor, before freeing memory. Read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete

```
delete a;
if (a != NULL) {
  a->~A();
  operator delete(a);
}
```

Very-very strange snippet. There is UB here.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/two-steps-of-delete.html: This is the link from where i got to now about delete p; implementation. So as per current thread discussion if i allocate memory in constructor then what should be my approach without using smart pointer. if i don't call the delete p inside the destructor How object which is constructed in constructor will be deleted.

Comment: If you read your link it's says that `delete a;` and `if (a != NULL) {
  a->~A();
  operator delete(a);
}`
are functionally equivalent, no need (and in fact, you should not) do both. `delete a;` is enough for any pointer allocated with `new`.

Comment: @FredericS for any? How about placement new?

Comment: @ForEveR placement new seems a bit off-topic considering OP question, and placement new is a different operator than `new` (using the same keyword, which is a bit confusing), so yes, for any.

Answer (score 0):

At all the places where new allocates the memory dynamically then we need to use **operator delete** to free the memory.Please check the description in the below mentioned link.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete